# How to set payment image icon on footer Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

've recently added Zipmoney as a payment option but my theme doesn't support the logo to display in the footer.
I've looked at the community answers which gave code to add to the footer template but my footer refers to another 'payment' icon file to display the icons. See copied code below. Just wondering if anyone can help me out with where I can add the logo image to display next to existing icons in the footer? And does it resize automagically? Or do I need to make sure the image I upload is the correct size?

```
      {{> components/common/payment-icons}}

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for easy. upload zip logo at image manager then open open /templates/components/common/payment-icons.html

paste that image code after like below sample

```
{{#if show_accept_visa}}
                <svg class=”footer-payment-icon”><use xlink:href=”#icon-logo-visa”></use></svg>
 {{/if}}
 
<img src="zip image path">
```